# Meta.Meta: Please add new close reason: Noise or Pointless

Tags: feature-request, meta, close-reasons

Like meta.stackoverflow.com, I think we need a "Noise or Pointless" close reason on meta.math.

(Note: I am talking about the meta site, not the parent).

Comment: It will be funny if this got closed :-)

Comment: This is a back-end issue. I have copied your request to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67393/close-reasons-on-meta-se-sites-should-be-consistent-with-mso.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like personal exasperation and not an analysis of the actual discussions on the meta.   I don't think the conversations have been as pointless or noisy as this feature-request indicates.  If this "feature" is added for consistency with SO, so be it, but that decision seems more a matter of convenience for the SO software providers than a need based on the meta discussions to date.

Comment: The site is not even out of Beta yet! The past 'history' we have is _nothing_ as compared to what meta.stackoverflow.com has. Besides, it was one of the questions posted recently which reminded me of this close reason. Nothing personal.

Comment: In that case why not wait and see whether a clear need does actually arise *here*, before deciding that it must and  pre-emptively adding another, dare I say "subjective and argumentative" (not to mention pejorative and acrimony-begetting), category of closable postings.  For many reasons, SO proper is not an all-purpose guide for how to run a math site.

Comment: It seems like you are arguing that this question needs to be closed as "Noise or pointless" ;-). I don't see any reason to wait and see. Just because the parent sites discuss different topics it does not mean we have to be different in every possible way. Frankly, I don't see how that is even relevant. Anyway...end of discussion for me. The mods can decide.

Comment: SO and MO have very different cultures and user base and that will probably also be true for math.SE after the beta. Not automatically replicating every bit of the SO environment is a matter of adapting to the particularities of the math site, not differentiation for its own sake.  As you say, site operators can decide this minor feature request (and I doubt anyone feels strongly about it), but math vs SO difference is a more general issue that I think should be kept firmly in mind as the site is developed.

Comment: There you go: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/929/which-other-comments